# Vim Regex: How do I search a string that doesn't contain another string?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to find a Vim regex that will  match `{% foo %}` but won't match if `foo` contains a pipe with the word `escape` somewhere after it.

So,

- `{% this is a test %}` matches
- `{% this is a test|something %}` matches
- `{% this is a test|escape %}` does not match
- `{% this is a test|something escape something-else %}` does not match

I've been experimenting with lookaheads and lookbehinds and I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about `\{%[^|]*?%\}`. The `[^|]` matches anything *except* a pipe. Also the `*?` means it's a possessive match, not a greedy one - it will stop if it sees `%}` as opposed to the default greedy behavior of matching until the last `%}` it finds.

Edit for comment: To avoid matches that contain the word "escape", you can, as you suggested, use negative lookahead: `(?!.*escape.*)\{%.*?%\}`.

Comment: The `?` is a good point. However, I'm realizing that I need to clarify my question: there might be a pipe, but `escape` can't be after it. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: two corrections and a related reference:

Comment: • `*?` and `+?` and `??` and `{2,3}?` in PCRE are called the **_lazy_ quantifiers**, also called: _reluctant_, _non-greedy_, _ungreedy_.  Not to be confused with the [_possessive_ quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `*+` and `++` and `?+` and `{m,n}+`

Comment: • **Vim’s idiosyncratic regex syntax** differs from PCRE: `/x*\?` and `/x\+\?` and `/x\?\?` and `/x\{2,3}\?` yield errors in Vim. (And in `/x*?` etc., Vim parses the `?` as a literal.)  Instead, the equivalents among [Vim’s lazy quantifiers](https://learnbyexample.github.io/vim_reference/Regular-Expressions.html#non-greedy-quantifiers) are: `/x\{-}` and `/x\{-1,}` and `/x{-,1}` and `/x\{-2,3}`

Comment: • Likewise, Vim does not have `*+` etc..  It does not even have any **possessive quantifiers** in the narrow sense.  But it provides the same functionality **via [atomic grouping](https://learnbyexample.github.io/vim_reference/Regular-Expressions.html#atomic-grouping)**: For PCRE’s `x*+` and `x++` and `x?+` and `x{m,n}+`   equivalents in Vim are: `\(x*\)\@>` (alternative `\v` `very magic` syntax: `\v(x*)@>`) and `\v(x+)@>` and `\v(x?)@>` and `\v(x{m,n})@>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look-ahead assertion:

```
(.*\|.*escape.*)@!
```

that checks that there won't be a pipe followed by the word `escape` until end of line, so now add the match for any string with non-greddy quantifier:

```
\s*.{-}
```

Note that I use the very-magic mode. It gets like:

```
/\v\{\%(.*\|.*escape.*)@!\s*.{-}\%\}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
\({%.*test.*|.*escape.*%}\)\@!{%.*test.*%}
```

explanation :

- {%.*test.*|.*escape.*%} : "test", then a pipe, then "escape" in {%...%}
- \(foo\)\@! : unmatch if the atom with "foo" is matched
- {%.*test.*%} : match what you want

"match, in a sentence not containing `{%` then `test` then `|` then `escape` then `%}`, the sentence `{%.\*test.\*%}`"